# Any Antimolecule so far?

Tags: antimatter, molecules

As i've been reading on Wikipedia, we are artificially able to join an antiproton with a positron to form an antihydrogen.

But if i search for antimolecule, i can't find any results on that, only a definition. Though they say that according to the laws of physics, antimatter follow the same rules (in their own domain).

So my question is, have we been able to form an antimolecule in the sense of a molecule composed by different "antiatoms" -
for example a molecule of $H_2O$ (2 hydrogen atoms, 1 Oxygen)?
Is there an antimolecule formed by 2 AntiHydrogen and 1 AntiOxygen.

Or for example an antimolecule for $H_2$ (without having to build an AntiOxygen)?

The main reason of this question is: is it proven that the forces that bind particles together and atoms together to form a molecule, apply similarly on antiparticles?

Comment: Wouldn't think so, even though we have seen anti-helium and even anti-lithium nuclei in heavy ion collider experiments. Theoretically one could expand that to make something like anti-LiH...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the main antihydrogen "factory" at CERN, [ALPHA.](http://alpha.web.cern.ch/) to see that they are still countin antihydrogen atoms one by one.

It is expected that the bonds of the antimolecules will be the same as for molecules, but to generate H2 from the few H held in a trap, have them at low enough energies to bond ( the [dissociation energy](http://www.eso.org/~tstanke/thesis/chap2_10.html) of the H2 molecule  is 4.48eV) would need a high statistics gas so that a few could turn into H2.

From the descriptions it does not appear that this can happen soon.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean with "high statistics gas", do you mean, you need a lot of H atoms in a trap, to increase the probability of an H2 forming, thus the same for AntiH? I think that maybe it is expected that antimolecules will form, just like molecules do, but i bet otherwise, and i know that scientists hate arrogants who speak like that, out of speculation... But how could that happen and matter dominates anti-matter? If we're ever able to make an antimolecule, it should be formed by different bonds and rules than the molecule's. and not even symmetrical, don't you agree?

Comment: I mean that to really have an antihydrogen  gas which would, by statistical evolution join to antiH2 one needs order of avogadro's number,~ 10^23 per mole. The mainstream physics models expect antihydrogen to form a molecule with the same bindings as hydrogen.

Comment: i didn't know that.. i'm a computer guy, who likes physics. But i need 1 gram of hydrogen (1 mole) to get H2 molecules? do i need 1 gram to start the triggering? how much a mole of H would produce of H2... cool that's new

Comment: However, there's no way antimolecules will form with the same bindings. Otherwise it would mean that god favors the right hand people, and right spinning particles, and that's not just. I think that left handed ppl are not the counter part of the right hand, but above all, there are people who don't write at all (didn't learn), and some lost their hands. and all ppl are equal in the eyes of god. but the antimatter odds are similar to an educated person who lost his hands

Comment: Look, if you are interested in physics you should study and learn more than you demonstrate with your comments. A mole has a strict definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_%28unit%29 . antimatter has nothing to do with left handed and right handed etc. try this  http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-antimatter-2002-01-24/